# Bash - heredoc with variable expansion, preserving newlines

Tags: bash

I am trying to generate the mail text for the send mail client `ssmtp` within a bash script (instead of putting it in a file).

Using `heredoc`s I came up with this:

```
MAILTO=me@mydomain.com
FROM=admin@mydomain.com
SUBJ="$HOSTNAME: Daemon not running"

read -d '' msg <<EOF
    To: $MAILTO
    From: $FROM
    Subject: $SUBJ

    Please check $HOSTNAME.
    Daemon has stopped running.

    -Admin
EOF

echo $msg | ssmtp $MAILTO
```

(This does not work. `ssmtp` does not send the mail, because the text does not preserve the newlines.)

If I `echo $msg`, then I see that the newlines in the heredoc are not preserved. How can I accomplish that?

Also: Where is the difference btw this

```
{
  echo "To: $MAILTO"
  echo "From: $FROM"
  echo "Subject: $SUBJ"
  echo
  echo "Please check $HOSTNAME"
} | ssmtp $MAILTO
```

and the first example? Are all `echo` commands executed and the result piped to `ssmtp`? Isn't this working in my first example? Can't I `echo` a text and pipe `echo`'s output to a command?

Comment: Use quotes `echo "$msg"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need `read` for this:

```
msg="\
To: $MAILTO
From: $FROM
Subject: $SUBJ

Please check $HOSTNAME.
Daemon has stopped running.

-Admin"
```

Second, you should *always* quote parameter expansions; you'll know when doing so isn't what you want, and such cases are rare.

```
echo "$msg" | ssmtp "$MAILTO"
```

Finally, consider whether you *need* `msg` in the first place:

```
ssmtp "$MAILTO" <<EOF
To: $MAILTO
From: $FROM
Subject: $SUBJ

Please check $HOSTNAME.
Daemon has stopped running.

-Admin
EOF
```

Comment: I like your second example. What I am missing is the abilitiy to indent this in a function. - Or can I indent it if I use `-EOF`?

Comment: I needed to capture `msg` because in my real-life-script I generate a large email text somewhere in the script with various data and then pass it to a function that sends the mail via `ssmtp`.

Comment: You can, as long as you are sure to indent *only* with tabs; only leading tabs are stripped, which can make it tricky to match the indentation of the surrounding code.

Comment: If you are worried about indentation, I would go with the `{ ... } | ...` approach; the overhead of multiple `echo`s vs one `echo` should be negligible.

Comment: I think that as the way I'll do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your second example uses [Command Grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html). So your assumption, that all `echo` commands are executed and piped to `ssmtp` is correct.

From the manual:

> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created.

Regarding your first example. This is not the heredoc's fault. Try to enclose `msg` in quotes:

```
echo "$msg" | ssmtp "$MAILTO"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. -  Is there a way to assign the result of a command group to a variable instead of piping it to a command? Because that would give me the possibility to indent the grouped commands within a function and align my code (for readabilities sake).

Comment: Got it! it must be possible via `OUTPUT=${expression}`

Comment: That did't work. But this does: `msg=$( echo "Peter"; echo; echo "Pan" )`, but no newline is inserted. Hmm... Need to learn a lot about Bash :)