# Problem sending variables to email using Bash and ssmtp

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, ssmtp

I am trying to send an email using Bash and `ssmtp`. I have gathered the login data from the `/var/log/auth.log` file and generated the email content. However, when I try to send the email, the variables are not being sent.

Here is the script I am using:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Gather login data
login_data=$(journalctl -u dropbear.service | grep "Password")

# Generate email content
email_content="Login Data:\n${login_data}"

# Send email using ssmtp
sync
ssmtp -m nodododi@example.com < <(echo "${email_content}")
```

I have tried using the `flush` command instead of the `sync` command, but it does not make a difference. I have also tried using the `wait` command to wait for the `ssmtp` command to exit before exiting the script, but it does not make a difference either.

I have also tried using the mail command instead of the ssmtp command, and it works

```
echo "${email_content}" | mail -s "hey" "nonodoid@example.com"
```

I am it happy it works with mail, but i want to understand better the ssmtp command, I read is more reliable

I found a similar question on Stack Overflow, but the solution is not related: [ssmtp cannot email my bash variable received from python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813116/ssmtp-cannot-email-my-bash-variable-received-from-python-subprocess)

Operating system: dietpi

Details:

- The message using ssmtp is completely empty, not even the label "login data"
- Echoing the `\n` does not make a new line. The mail send with the mail command change line with the `\n`
- Output using `set -x` at the top:

  ```
  Nov 07 19:48:18 DietPi dropbear[15323]: [15323] Nov 07 19:48:18 Password auth succeeded for '\''root'\'' from ip:12342
  Nov 07 22:56:28 DietPi dropbear[18942]: [18942] Nov 07 22:56:28 Password auth succeeded for '\''root'\'' from from ip:12342
  Nov 08 10:59:19 DietPi dropbear[24025]: [24025] Nov 08 10:59:19 Password auth succeeded for '\''root'\'' from from ip:12342
  Nov 08 19:14:44 DietPi dropbear[30112]: [30112] Nov 08 19:14:44 Password auth succeeded for '\''root'\'' from from ip:12342
  ```
- The script is run in bash. version: 5.2.15(1)-release
- `echo -e` does not make a change.

I think the problem lies in the sstmp command. The mail function works good with the same `echo` command

```
echo  "$failed_login" | mail -s "failed" "example@example.com"
```

ssmtp without the variable sends text:

```
echo  "login_data" | ssmtp - m example@example.com
```

Comment: Have you looked at any error messages the script is printing? Are you certain this is running in bash, not some other shell? Process substitution with `<( )` is a bash-only feature, and will fail in most other shells (and even bash when run by the name "sh"). I'd use a plain old here-document instead (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354123/bash-heredoc-with-variable-expansion-preserving-newlines)).

Comment: Why would you need the `sync` command? The script doesn't write any files. The only purpose of that command is to ensure you don't lose data in a system crash, it has no visible effect otherwise.

Comment: FYI `< <(echo "${email_content}")` is equivalent to `<<< "$email_content"`. [edit] your question to show the output you get if you add `set -x` to the top of your script, right below the shebang line.

Comment: When you say "the variables are not being sent", what do you mean? Does the message contain the label `Login Data:` without the value of `$login_data`?

Comment: note that `echo` doesn't treat `\n` as a newline unless you use `echo -e`.

Comment: Also show in your question what happens when you just run `ssmtp -m nodododi@example.com foobar` from the command line. You should really be using an @example.com email address for all questions btw.

Comment: expanding on @Barmar's comment: echo does not treat `\n` as a newline unless you use `-e` AND if you are using a version of `echo` that supports that functionality.  Don't guess; use `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to `ssmtp` should be a well-formed RFC5322 message, not some random string data. Try this:

```
ssmtp - m nonombrable@example.com <<____here
Subject: no subject
From: yourself <me@example.net>
To: recipient <nonombrable@example.com>

$email_content
____here
```

Collecting the output in a string variable just so you can then immediately interpolate it back once is just a waste of memory; here is a more efficient approach.

```
( printf '%s\n' "Subject: Login data" \
    "From: yourself <me@example.net>" \
    "To: recipient <nonombrable@example.com>" \
    "" \
    "Login Data:"
    journalctl -u dropbear.service | grep "Password"
) | ssmtp -m nodododi@example.com
```

Generally, you don't want to piece together email messages from pieces of string if you can avoid it; there are many corner cases where you need a deep understanding of the relevant RFCs and MIME standards etc.

`sync` has nothing to do with this; it (requires root and) writes out any pending disk writes to your hard drive.

Also, `\n` in a string is just `\n`; but e.g. `printf` interprets this and a number of other escape codes. Bash also has `$'C-style strings\nwhere\tthis\a works'` and `echo -e` (but probably prefer `printf` which is more portable as well as more elegant and versatile).

*Some* mail servers will assume that you have empty headers and artificially add an empty line (or syntesized headers) above the message you provide when it is obviously malformed, but this isn't reliable (and "obviously malformed" typically means "does not have a colon immediately after the first token" which surprisingly often your malformed message will also have; for example, that was the problem with the near-duplicate question you found).

Comment: the more efficient aproach worked perfectly. printf is definetely more versatile. thanks!!!!